# How can I shorten the time it takes to switch between Applied Steps in Power Query?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerbi, powerquery

I'm building a report in Excel using Power Query (long-time user).  The latency is worse than I've ever experienced.

When using the Power Query Editor and clicking on an Applied Step to only VIEW the results (not editing the code or steps in any way) it can take 10 minutes or more for that step to render in the UI.

NOTE: These are steps I've already created and even loaded to the worksheet a few times.

Also, when I'm adding a step, Power Query seems to re-load all of the previous steps before showing the results of the newly applied step.  In the status bar it will show that it's loading mega- or even gigabytes of data from the source .csv files.  The amount of data is vastly more than the original source file from which it's reading.

Is this normal?  Are there other settings that will speed up Power Query?

1. I started with my 3 .xlsx source files in SharePoint.
2. Then tried pulling the data from the 3 .xlsx files on my local C: drive.
3. Then I set up the 3 sample data files (on local C: drive) with about 200 lines of data. (a much smaller set than the original sources)
4. Then I moved the data from the source file into the current workbook.
5. Finally, I converted the 3 .xlsx files to .csv files on my local C: drive and used those as sources.

At each step I expected some performance improvement.  Only switching to .csv files did I see any improvement.  However, I expected the latency between clicking to view a step and the results rendering on screen to be much less.  Even a simple step like renaming a Step or removing a column is unbearably slow (10-30 seconds)

In SETTINGS, I've also:
Enabled 'Never detect column types and headers for unstructured sources'
cleared the cache
Enabled 'Never allow data previews to download in the background.'
Enabled 'Always ignore Privacy Level settings.'

Here is the code referenced above:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\PATH TO CSV DATA FILE"),
    
    /* auto generated when I loaded the data source using the UI buttons */
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
    /* end auto gen M code */
    
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Expanded Table Column1",2),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Fixed Column Header Names" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Project Task ", "Project Task"}, {"Expenditure Type ", "Expenditure Type"}, {"Org ", "Org"}, {"Projects ", "Projects"}, {"Activity ", "Activity"}, {"Program ", "Program"}, {"Account ", "Account"}, {"FinancialUnit ", "FinancialUnit"}, {"NetAssetClass ", "NetAssetClass"}, {"Entity ", "Entity"}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Fixed Column Header Names",{"Business Unit", "Department", "Payroll", "E_Number", "E_Name", "Assignment Number", "Element Classification", "Element", "Entity", "NetAssetClass", "FinancialUnit", "Account", "Program", "Activity", "Projects", "Org", "Expenditure Type", "Project Task", "Process", "Project Name", "Project Type", "Period Start Date", "Period End Date", "Process Date", "Date Earned", "Accounting Date", "Debit Amount", "Credit Amount"}),
    #"Filter Elements" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each List.Contains(lCostingElementClassifications,[Element])),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filter Elements",{{"Debit Amount", type number}, {"Credit Amount", type number}}),
    #"Added TOTAL AMOUNT"= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "TOTAL AMOUNT", each [Debit Amount] - [Credit Amount], Currency.Type),
    #"Removed Debit Credit Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added TOTAL AMOUNT",{"Debit Amount", "Credit Amount"}),
    #"Added EFFORT COSTING PROJECT" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Debit Credit Columns", "PC NUMBER", each if [Project Type] = "" then [#"Entity"] & "." & [#"NetAssetClass"] & "." & [#"FinancialUnit"] & "." & [#"Account"] & "." & [#"Program"] & "." & [#"Activity"] & "." else if List.Contains( {"Cores", "Gift and Endowment Temporary", "Gift and Endowment Unrestricted"}, [Project Type]) then [#"Projects"] & "." & [#"Project Task"] & "." else [#"Projects"] & "." & [#"Project Task"] & "."),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added EFFORT COSTING PROJECT", {"PC NUMBER"}, qProjectsML, {"PN.TN."}, "qProjectsML", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded qMasterList" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "qProjectsML", {"NET ASSET CLASS (NAC)", "Program", "Activity"}, {"qProjectsML.NET ASSET CLASS (NAC)", "qProjectsML.Program", "qProjectsML.Activity"}),
    #"Added TRUE NAC" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded qMasterList", "TRUE NAC", each if [Projects] = "0000" then [NetAssetClass] else [#"qProjectsML.NET ASSET CLASS (NAC)"]),
    #"Added TRUE Program" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added TRUE NAC", "TRUE PROGRAM", each if [Projects] = "0000" then [Program] else [qProjectsML.Program]),
    #"Added TRUE Activity" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added TRUE Program", "TRUE ACTIVITY", each if [Projects] = "0000" then [Activity] else [qProjectsML.Activity]),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added TRUE Activity", {"E_Number"}, qRosterML, {"Person Number"}, "qRosterML", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded qRosterML" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "qRosterML", {"Work Unit", "Job Code", "Job Title", "Position Name", "JCAT", "Full/Part Time", "Regular/Temporary"}, {"qRosterML.Work Unit", "qRosterML.Job Code", "qRosterML.Job Title", "qRosterML.Position Name", "qRosterML.JCAT", "qRosterML.Full/Part Time", "qRosterML.Regular/Temporary"})
in
    #"Expanded qRosterML"
```

*<sub>NOTE: I'm not talking about when I load the Power Query results to a worksheet.  I'm also not talking about the amount of time it takes to refresh the queries.  My issue is in the EDITOR while VIEWING Applied Steps one at a time and while adding a new Applied Step during the development phase.</sub>*

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using **parameters** to reduce the amount of data during report development. Only after the report has been published,  I change those parameters in the *Power BI Service* to production settings.